# Update parent whenever a control changes value in WPF

Tags: wpf, user-controls

Is it possible for a User control to receive an update whenever a user control changes value? I have a form with a save button and I want to activate it as soon as a value changes.

Currently I am ding this using my View but I have to add a call to every property when it changes. This is OK but for edit boxes it means the user has to tab away before the save button becomes active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bind your view to a view model then you can have a flag IsDirty inside view model which will be set every time you fire PropertyChanged event

```
    protected void FirePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        _isDirty = true;
        if(handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Then bind your button with IsDirty

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a IsDirty boolean property which is changed whenever a value is changed.
Couple the IsEnabled property of the save button to the IsDirty boolean.

If it is in a class you want to have to be decoupled, use an event/notification.